# OpenMp: How to make dimensional std::vector threadprivate

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am new to the OpenMp world and got an error, which i cant fix.
The original Code is way to big, so i made a small code to summarize the problem:

I got a more dimensional `std::vector` (2d and 3d), which should not be shared between the threads. If i mark them as private, they still cause memory errors, because the threads still share them.

I came up with an fix for that problem: 
I created 1 more dimension for the 2d vector, so each thread can access his own copy:

```
myVector[omp_get_thread_num()][1].push_back(i);
```

I know this is not a smart fix for my problem, but now each thread got their own copy of the 2d Vector.
Now comes the strange part: This still causes memory crashes sometimes if i dont put `#pragma omp critial` in front of it.
I dont really understand why it is necessary, because the threads should never access the same memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>

//this should represent my problem(without my fix)
int main(){
        std::vector < std::vector < int > > v;
    v.resize(3);

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) private(v)
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            v[1].push_back(i); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope there is a better solution to make my 2d vector threadprivate.

ps. it is not possible to allocate the vector inside the omp part.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you highlight what is your problem exactely

Comment: My problem: even if i "mark" my vector v as private. all threads share the same copy of it. So they will access the same memory and cause memory errors. It works fine for 1d vector, but with a 2d vector the private(v) seems to have no affect

Comment: In your code, private vectors `v` in a parallel section are _default-constructed_. Consequently, they are empty and `v[1]` causes undefined behavior (likely exhibited as a memory error).

Comment: _I know this is not a smart fix for my problem._ Why not? If you need to, e.g., access these vectors after a parallel section ends, it's perfectly fine. I would just care about _false sharing_, since in the outer-most dimension, vector objects of individual threads are placed next to each other in memory. Their modification (e.g., change of size or capacity) might then suffer from false sharing.

Comment: Thank you, what should i do to prevent the false sharing? I dont know how big the vectors will be in the end, so they increase size and capacity multiple times.

Comment: @Rapha167 It depends. You don't provide enough details. For instance, do you need all threads' vectors to exist after a parallel section ends? If so, you can put them into a _list_ instead of a _vector_. With a list, false sharing is less likely. Another possibility is to put into a vector only pointers to vectors and create them dynamically.

Comment: @Daniel Langr No, the vector dont need to exist after the parallel region. Its a 2D vector, that has a unknown size/capacity during the function, but is empty at the end. Your solution to put only pointers into the vector is something that came to my mind before. Maybe i can try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that variables coming from an outside scope that are declared `private` work as if they are locally declared **without an initializer**. So each local copy is an empty vector, hence your code can't work.

Generally, it is better with OpenMP to declare private variables locally - that way you avoid a lot of confusion between the "outside value" and "inside private values" which are not connected at all. You can do this by splitting the `parallel` and `for` directives.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
    v.resize(3);
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        v[1].push_back(i); 
    }
}
```

Note that `v` is not available after the parallel region - this is good! In your original example `v` is available after the parallel region - but it's value has nothing to do with the value from the threads inside.

If you need to retain the information from `v`, you may want to look at reduction, but it depends on your specific use case.

Your approach of `myVector[omp_get_thread_num()]` a common naive approach. This code is **correct**, but in any case where you *modify the values of the outermost vector*, it has **bad performance** due to false sharing.

```
myVector[omp_get_thread_num()].push_back(); // Bad performance
myVector[omp_get_thread_num()][1].push_back(i); // Ok
```

So it is generally advisable to not do this and use locally declared variables instead. Nevertheless, if this code of yours crashes, there is something else wrong. In that case you need to prepare a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and please ask a second question (referencing this).

Now `threadprivate` is something different than `private`. `private` is usually what you want and refers to the specific task / scope. In most cases, you don't need or want `threadprivate`.

Comment: this answer helped me a lot, thank you! As i dont need v after the parallel region i will try your solution. My problem is, that v is declared in a header file. So if i change it and declare it in a parallel region i need to pass a pointer to the vector to A LOT of functions. But as you mentioned if i want a good speedup i have no other choice

Comment: Global variables with threads don't mix well. I'd strongly recommend to extend your interfaces. If you really must... applying a `threadprivate` directive to the global variable can work. But its much harder to reason about - and I can't give any recommendation how to because I don't know your application good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the thread_local storage specifier:

```
int main(){
   thread_local std::vector < std::vector < int > > v;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: It is generally not advisable to mix C++ threading concepts (such as the `thread_local` storage specifier) with OpenMP.

Comment: Thanks Zulan, thats good to know. Is there a "open mp way" of fixing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify many important details about your original code. However, one way might be to create a parallel section first and define private vectors within and then to parallelize the loop. For your exemplary code, it might look like:

```
int main() {
   #pramga omp parallel
   {
      std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
      v.resize(3);

      #pragma omp for 
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         v[1].push_back(i); 
   }
}
```